# Prolog - Replacing X number of elements of a list after element of order I

Tags: list, replace, prolog, element

I'm trying to implement a predicate that replaces NumElm elements of a list after (and including) a given Index. For that I use another predicate that replaces an element of a list.
My code so far is:

```
replace([_|T], 0, X, [X|T]).
replace([H|T], I, X, [H|R]):- 
  I > -1,
  NI is I-1,
  replace(T, NI, X, R), !.
replace(L, _, _, L).

replaceX(_,_,0,_,_).
replaceX(Line,Index,NumElm,Elm,NLine) :-
  replace(Line,Index,Elm,BLine),
  Index1 is Index+1,
  NumElm1 is NumElm-1,
  replaceX(BLine,Index1,NumElm1,Elm,Nline).
```

With that code, only the first element, the one of order Index, is replaced.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.
[EDIT] The result of the previous code was just 'yes'. The one that replaced the first element was the following:

```
replace([_|T], 0, X, [X|T]).
replace([H|T], I, X, [H|R]):- 
  I > -1,
  NI is I-1,
  replace(T, NI, X, R), !.
replace(L, _, _, L).

replaceX(_,_,0,_,_).
replaceX(Line,Index,NumElm,Elm,NLine) :-
  replace(Line,Index,Elm,NLine),
  Index1 is Index+1,
  NumElm1 is NumElm-1,
  replaceX(NLine,Index1,NumElm1,Elm,Nline).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to define the first clause of replaceX with:

```
replaceX(A,_,0,_,A):-!.
```

The reasoning behind this is explained by how `_` works: it names an anonymous variable, and each instance of `_` names a different variable. [Here's](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=singleton) an explanation. The cut, on the other hand, helps you get rid of undesired backtracking.

I think `Nline` in the last line should be `NLine`. Also you're lacking a dot at the end of the second `replace` clause.

Edit:

```
replace([_|T], 0, X, [X|T]).
replace([H|T], I, X, [H|R]):- 
  I > -1,
  NI is I-1,
  replace(T, NI, X, R), !.
replace(L, _, _, L).

replaceX(A,_,0,_,A):- !.
replaceX(Line,Index,NumElm,Elm,NLine) :-
  replace(Line,Index,Elm,BLine),
  Index1 is Index+1,
  NumElm1 is NumElm-1,
  replaceX(BLine,Index1,NumElm1,Elm,NLine).
```

Example input:

```
?- replaceX([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],2,4,a,R).
R = [0,1,a,a,a,a,6].
```

Isn't that the expected result?

Comment: Do you mean adding that clause or replacing mine with yours? Either way, the output is just yes.

Comment: Replacing yours. I'll edit to include the code. What is the interpreter you are using? I know most universities in Brazil use SWI prolog, which is what I tested this on

Answer (score 0):

handling numeric indexing can be tedious in Prolog, I would write

```
replace(L, From, To, X, R) :-
    findall(S, (nth0(I,L,E), (I>=From, I<To ->S = X ; S = E)), R).
```

that yields

```
?- replace([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 2,4,a, R).
R = [0, 1, a, a, 4, 5, 6].
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't learned that syntax yet, so I'm not sure I can use it. Thanks, though

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
replace( As     , _ , 0 , _ , As     ) .  % special case: nothing left to replace.
replace( [A|As] , P , N , X , [A|Bs] ) :- % otherwise,
  P > 0 ,                                 % - if the position counter is greater than zero,
  P1 is P-1 ,                             % - decrement it, stow the current item to the result list
  replace( As , P1 , N , X , Bs )         % - and recurse down
  .                                       %
replace( [_|As] , 0 , N , X , [X|Bs] ) :- % otherwise, if the position count is decremented to zero
  N > 0 ,                                 % - but the length counter is greater than zero,
  N1 is N-1 ,                             % - decrement it, stow X in the result list
  replace( As , 0 , N1 , X , Bs )         % - and recurse down.
  .                                       %
```